# ROS2 coexistence with ROS

Tags: ros, ros2

If I have installed ROS in my linux machine, can I install ROS2 and use both without problems?

I have already installed ROS and I am using it to learn the concept but the system in which I have to work in the end is in ROS2.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, both ROS1 and ROS2 can co-exist.
Source the appropriate `setup.bash` to depending on which version of ROS you want to use.
For ROS1: `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`
For ROS2: `source /opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash`

Comment: Thanks. I have put that source in the `.bashrc` file. If I want to use one (ROS) and then the other(ROS2) do I have to edit this file? (meaning I cannot put both at the same time)

Comment: Whichever file was sourced last will be the one which is active. I would suggest you create aliases for both of them and use them when needed. Adding them both to `.bashrc` won't is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use ROS1 with ROS2 (and if you want you can use different distributions together from the same ROS version), the only requirement is to source the correct setup.bash file:

`source /opt/ros/[distribution]/setup.bash`

If you want to use ROS1 and ROS2 in the same application, checkout the ROS2 package called [ROS1_bridge](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge) which allows you to connect ROS1 topics to ROS2 topics (or vica versa).

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Shrijit Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2661982/shrijit-singh) comment, you need to create in your home directory the file .bash_aliases and then write:

```
alias source-ros='source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash'
alias source-ros2='source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash'
```

Then you just need to type in your terminal either source-ros or source-ros2
You do not need to add something in .bashrc as .bash_alias is automatically loaded from there.

Comment: You can source (and use) both, so it's not 'either or'.